# 次のようなリンクを遷移できるテーブルを作りたい。　td #{user.name} = link_to "[#{user.age}]", '#遷移先URL'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

ユーザー名、年齢、emailを表示させるテーブルを作成しております。
そこで、ユーザー名と年齢は以下のような構成で表示し、その上で、年齢のみに
リンクを設定し、遷移できるようにしたいです。

※年齢用のtdを追加するのが簡単ですが、どうしても今回はユーザー名の隣に表示させたいです。

例
田中[29]
村田[21]

```
table.table
  thead
    tr
      td #{user.name} [#{user.age}]
      td #{user.email}
```

そこで、以下のようにできないかと考えていたのですが、うまくいきませんでした。

```
td #{user.name}
  = link_to "[#{user.age}]", '#遷移先URL'
```

この先、どうすればよいかわからず困っております。

よろしければ助言いただけないでしょうか？
宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こんな感じで実現できるはずです。（ViewのテンプレートエンジンはSlimですよね？）

```
td
  = user.name
  = link_to "[#{user.age}]", '#遷移先URL'
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。ローカルの環境でも再現出来ました。仰るとおり、Slimです。明記しておけばよかったです・・・。